# delete users on the basis of comments in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

good morning, everybody...

i have one user discussion forum page in my WordPress site, in order to make comments user must have to register first. But i have seen that many user make registration but does not post single comments in a month. so i have to manually check the comments and then delete that particular user.

my question is that is there any way to auto delete user that have not make any single comments in a month.

can anybody help me in order to perform my task.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$args = array('user_id' => $current_user->ID);
$usercomment = get_comments($args);
if(count($usercomment) < 1){
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
wp_delete_user( $current_user->ID );
} 
else {
            //
 }
```

Check this code it will remove user if user comment is less then 1 . i thnik it will give  you idea